# Adding timestamp to Rails AppLogger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following logger class:

```
module AppLogger
  @@_loggers = {}

  def self.logger; self._creater_logger("my_app_name"); end

  def self._creater_logger(name)
    @@_loggers[name] ||= $0 == "irb" ? Logger.new(STDOUT) : Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log",Rails.env + ".#{name}.log"))
  end

  def self.format_exception(e)
    "#{e.message} [[\n\t\t#{e.backtrace.split("\n").map { |l| "\t\t#{l}" }.join("\n")}]]"
  end
end
```

and to use it:

```
AppLogger.logger.info(msg)
```

Is there a way to automatically add the timestamp to each log row (without manually adding it to each call to the logger)?

Answer (score 0):

You could redefine a singleton of your class and add all or some levels of logging levels.

```
%w(debug info warn error fatal).each do |level|
  eval <<-end_eval
    def Applogger.logger.#{level}(message="", &blk)
      if message == "" and block_given?
        message = blk.call
      end
      super(<you time stamp>) { message }
    end
  end_eval
end
```

Basically add what ever your heart desires in the super method.

I grabbed this code from an old blog post of mine where I had to add custom info to my logger you could refer to that for more details.

http://www.snitchmedia.com/blog/2009/11/24/pimping-ruby-logger-instance/